# When Gradle's hooks are added in build lifecycle?

Tags: gradle, hook, lifecycle

In Gradle there are plenty of hooks. But I can't understand exactly when they are applied.
 From the docs I found hooks for the build and for a project:

addListener(listener)

afterProject(closure)

beforeProject(closure)

buildFinished(closure)

settingsEvaluated(closure)

taskGraph.whenReady

projectsLoaded

***For project***

project.afterEvaluate()

project.beforeEvaluate()

So I tried to make representation of figure from the book Gradle in Action (*Muschko, Benjamin. "Hooking into the Build Lifecycle." Gradle in Action. N.p.: n.p., 2014. 100. Print.*) to receive better idea for the whole picture when and where the hooks are apply?

So when the hook are added and if there other build, project hooks?

[image]

Comment: I also have been searching all hooking points in the Gradle process. 
Is anybody explain more in detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks about right. (I assume the question is when callbacks are *executed*.) `gradle.projectsLoaded` needs to go between initialization and configuration phase. `gradle.beforeProject` happens at certain points during the configuration phase. Check out `Gradle` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for other callbacks.

Comment: feel free to correct my question.

I still don't understand when afterEvaluate() and beforeEvaluate() are executed?

beforeEvaluate() at 5 or 6?</br>
afterEvaluate() after beforeEvaluate at 6???

Comment: Same as `beforeProject` and `afterProject`, just for a specific project.

Comment: SO if they are used at the same time a in single project build first is beforeProject, then beforeEvaluate, afterEvaluate, afterProject?

Comment: The docs don't say whether `gradle.beforeProject` or `project.beforeEvaluate` comes first, so it is unspecified.

Comment: @Xelian beforeEvaluate() is triggered before we start our configuration phase and in single-project build quite often it's useless.
Respectively afterEvaluate() is triggered after we finish our configuration phase.