# Is there an Android gradle build task dependencies diagram?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is there an equivalent diagram to this for the Android gradle plugin?
[image: Java plugin - tasks]
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N12255

Comment: Officially, this is the documentation:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks

Comment: I am aware. And that equivalent diagram, does not exist...in fact, that page has no diagrams on it. ;(

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found any diagram for Android gradle plugin, **BUT** I've found a way to create it for any project/library/module.

Add [`Inspector`](https://github.com/jakeouellette/inspector) library to your top level `gradle.build` file and execute task you want to inspect. Then check `./buildProfile/report` folder.

Just for instance my top level `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.jakeout:inspector:0.3.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jakeout.gradle-inspector"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is part of report for my simple project:
[image: Android task dependencies]

**P.S.** Maybe, generated image is not that good as created by Gradle team, but good enough to understand dependencies in your project/library/module.

Comment: Currently working on a complex, multi-flavour Android Gradle project. This is going to save me hours of poking around. Thank you!

Comment: @MattMatt, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Putting this here, because it is the closest I've found so far...but it doesn't explicitly reference the gradle tasks required to reach these steps... :(

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-workflow

Comment: That diagram also notes that "the NDK workflow is not currently supported by the Gradle build system"

Answer (score 0):

This link may have what you are looking for (best I could find):

[When Gradle's hooks are added in build lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638691/when-gradles-hooks-are-added-in-build-lifecycle)

https://github.com/akhikhl/gradle-onejar

http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/
(Diagram partway down the page)

Comment: Very neat, but not android-specific.